# Running groovy script from Jenkins Script Console vs Dynamic Choice Parameter

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have a deployer job which tries to find build names from another job. I'm trying to limit the number of builds returned to only those which have been promoted. I tried debugging my code in the Jenkins Script Console and it seems to work, however when I put the same code inside the Dynamic Choice Parameter -> Choices Script I have different behavior. Here's the code:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.plugins.promoted_builds.*

def getPromotedBuildNames(Job job, String promotionName) {
    def buildNames = []
    (job.getBuilds()).each { build ->
        (build.getActions(PromotedBuildAction)).each { action ->
            if (action.contains(promotionName)) {
                buildNames.add(build.displayName)
            }
        }
    }
    return buildNames
}

def job1 = findJobByName(...)

return getPromotedBuildNames(job1, "PROMOTED")
```

One issue I had, that the script was failing as PromoteBuildAction.class was not defined. I used the Dynamic Choice Parameter -> Class Paths and set it to **/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/promoted-builds/WEB-INF/lib/promoted-builds.jar** This made my script compile, however I receive 0 results back from getActions().

I have little groovy experience and don't know about Jenkins internals. Could you help? Thanks.